# Is there a single word for "group of intelligent people"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please, suggest any single word that can define the meaning of this following phrase:

> Group of intelligent people.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. For single-word-requests we require an example sentence showing where the word will fit. For this question I think it is pretty obvious, but I suggest you edit the question to include this anyway.

Comment: The illuminati. The mystagogues. The help.

Answer (score 3):

[**intelligentsia**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intelligentsia)

The intellectual elite of a society.

Answer (score 2):

[**Intellectuals**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intellectual) fit your description.

[**Upper crust**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/upper+crust)

The highest social class or group.

[**Elite**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elite+group)

elite group - a group or class of persons enjoying superior intellectual or social or economic status

Comment: I think you should edit [your here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303270/is-the-following-sentence-an-imperative-sentence)  and post it up again. You could just say "it isn't an imperative, but it's a use of "anadiplodocus" or whatever it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[Geniuses](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/genius?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)**:

> A person having an exceptional natural capacity of intellect, especially as shown in creative and original work in science, art, music, etc.
>
> A person having an extraordinarily high intelligence rating on a psychological test, as an IQ above 140

or possibly **[Boffins](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boffin?s=t)**:

> A scientist or technical expert